# Normalization of One-Particle States using Dirac Delta Function

Tags: hilbert-spaces, dirac-delta, quantum-field-theory

I am attempting to understand the normalization of one-particle state $|\textbf{p}\rangle \propto a_{\textbf{p}}^\dagger$ in the context of Klein-Gordon field quantization from Peskin & Schroder's QFT textbook (page no. 22-23).

They compute $\langle\textbf{p}|\textbf{q}\rangle = (2\pi)^3 \delta(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q})$ and demonstrate that it is not Lorentz invariant by considering the effect of a boost in the 3-direction. Under such a boost we have $p_3' = \gamma(p_3 + \beta E)$ and $E' = \gamma (E+\beta p_3)$, where the symbols have their usual meanings in the discussion of Lorentz transformation. They recommend using the following Dirac delta identity:

$$\delta(f(x) - f(x_0)) = \frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{\vert f'(x_0) \vert}$$

and with that they show that

$$\delta(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}) = \delta(\textbf{p}'-\textbf{q}') \frac{E'}{E}.$$ (I put their calculation in the Appendix.)

To reproduce the result, I started in the following way.

$$
\delta(\textbf{p}'-\textbf{q}') = \delta(p'_1-q'_1)\delta(p'_2-q'_2)\delta(p'_3-q'_3) \\
= \delta(p_1-q_1) \, \delta(p_2-q_2) \, \delta[\gamma(p_3 + \beta E_p) - \gamma(q_3 + \beta E_q)],
$$
where $E_p = \sqrt{|\textbf{p}|^2 + m^2} = \sqrt{p_1^2 + p_2^2 + p_3^2 + m^2}$ and $E_q = \sqrt{|\textbf{q}|^2 + m^2} = \sqrt{q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2 + m^2}$ and $m$ is the mass of the particle. Here, I have dropped the primes in the argument first two Dirac delta functions as $p_1, q_1$ and $p_2, q_2$ do not change due to boost considered.

**My Question**

From here I am not sure how to proceed or use the Dirac Delta identity to get to the final result. Could you please help me here a little bit?

**Appendix**

[image]

Comment: Related Phys.SE post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $f$ you want to use the identity on is $$f(x) = \gamma (x+ \beta E(x)),$$
where

$$E(x) = \sqrt{p_1^2+p_2^2+ x^2 +m^2}.$$

Then taking the derivative  $$f'(x) = \gamma(1+ \beta \frac{dE}{dx}(x)).$$

So the identity gives

$$\delta(p_3'-q_3')=\delta(p_3-q_3)\frac{1}{\gamma(1+\beta \frac{dE}{dx}(q_3))}$$

and one can calculate

$$\frac{dE}{dx}(p_3) = \frac{p_3}{E(p_3)}.$$

Now just multiply the denominator over

$$\begin{align}\delta(p_3-q_3) &= \delta(p_3'-q_3')\gamma(1+\beta \frac{dE}{dx}(p_3))\\
&=\delta(p_3'-q_3')\frac{\gamma}{E(p_3)}(E(p_3)+\beta p_3)\\
&=\delta(p_3'-q_3')\gamma\frac{E'(p_3)}{E(p_3)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My confusion is as follows. To apply the formula for the case of $\delta(p_3' - q_3') = \delta(f(p_3) - f(q_3))$, we have the followings. $p_3' = f(p_3) = \gamma \left(p_3 + \beta \sqrt{|\textbf{p}|^2 + m^2}\right)$. But $f(q_3) = \gamma\left(q_3 + \beta \sqrt{p_1^2+p_2^2+q_3^2 + m^2}\right) \neq  \gamma\left(q_3 + \beta \sqrt{|\textbf{q}|^2 + m^2}\right) = q_3'$. Then how can the formula can be implemented here?

Comment: Most probably, I am missing some important aspect of your answer. Also, I have another question. When I write, for instance, $p_3' = f(p_3)$, why do I consider $p_1$ and $p_2$ as constants? Shouldn't we consider $p_3'$ as a function of $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$?

Comment: when multiplied by deltas $\delta(p_1-q_1)$ and $\delta(p_2-q_2)$ they are the same.

Comment: @podiki How did you go from equation 4, where you have $\frac{dE}{dx}(q_3)$ to equation 6, where you have $\frac{dE}{dx}(p_3)$? Is it because of the delta?

Comment: @AjayShanmugaSakthivasan exactly, there is a factor of $\delta(q_3-p_3)$ in front of this equation so any expression attached equates these two values.